# How can I use the JAR tool with Bazel v0.19+?

Tags: bazel

Starting with Bazel v0.19, if you have Starlark (formerly known as "Skylark") code that references `@bazel_tools//tools/jdk:jar`, you see messages like this at build time:

```
WARNING: <trimmed-path>/external/bazel_tools/tools/jdk/BUILD:79:1: in alias rule @bazel_tools//tools/jdk:jar: target '@bazel_tools//tools/jdk:jar' depends on deprecated target '@local_jdk//:jar': Don't depend on targets in the JDK workspace; use @bazel_tools//tools/jdk:current_java_runtime instead (see https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/issues/5594)
```

I think I could make things work with `@bazel_tools//tools/jdk:current_java_runtime` if I wanted access to the `java` command, but I'm not sure what I'd need to do to get the `jar` tool to work. The contents of the [linked GitHub issue](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/issues/5594) didn't seem to address this particular problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I stumbled across [a commit to Bazel](https://github.com/buchgr/bazel/commit/200819dd6c95e0574e894718b471c4dc1ca91194) that makes a similar adjustment to the Starlark java rules. It uses the following pattern: (I've edited the code somewhat)

```
# in the rule attrs:
    "_jdk": attr.label(
        default = Label("//tools/jdk:current_java_runtime"),
        providers = [java_common.JavaRuntimeInfo],
    ),

# then in the rule implementation:
    java_runtime = ctx.attr._jdk[java_common.JavaRuntimeInfo]
    jar_path = "%s/bin/jar" % java_runtime.java_home
     ctx.action(
         inputs = ctx.files._jdk + other inputs,
         outputs = [deploy_jar],
         command = "%s cmf %s" % (jar_path, input_files),
     )
```

Additionally, `java` is available at `str(java_runtime.java_executable_exec_path)` and `javac` at `"%s/bin/javac" % java_runtime.java_home`.

See also, [a pull request with a simpler example](https://github.com/meetup/rules_openapi/pull/7).

Comment: Thanks. I can see the logic in that. I'll try it today and accept this, as long as it works. :)

Comment: Trying to figure out what to do with this... That looks like exactly the right approach to use when you have a rule at the top level. In my case, I have a macro with a genrule directly inside it, so the solution is a bit different. Here's what I'll do: I'll put that in as a separate answer. If you're willing to grab it and incorporate it into yours, I'll just delete my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Because my reference to the jar tool is inside a genrule within top-level macro, rather than a rule, I was unable to use the approach from Rodrigo's answer. I instead explicitly referenced the `current_java_runtime` toolchain and was then able to use the [JAVABASE make variable](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/be/make-variables.html) as the base path for the jar tool.

```
native.genrule(
    name = genjar_rule,
    srcs = [<rules that create files being jar'd>],
    cmd = "some_script.sh $(JAVABASE)/bin/jar $@ $(SRCS)",
    tools = ["some_script.sh", "@bazel_tools//tools/jdk:current_java_runtime"],
    toolchains = ["@bazel_tools//tools/jdk:current_java_runtime"],
    outs = [<some outputs>]
)
```